# set orientation for single viewcontrollers not working for iPad

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set a single orientation for the first view controller only. So far I have tried:

**PLAN 1:**

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation");
```

**Result:**

But this applies to all `viewController` in the app. Then I used the below code in `viewWillDisappear` of `firstViewController`:

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.All.rawValue, forKey: "orientation");
```

But in All `viewController`

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape { print("Not called")}
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait { print("Not called")}
```

**PLAN 2:**

I used the following:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
return .portrait

}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
return .portrait
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
return false
}
```

**Result:**

Not working.

Do we have another solution?

Comment: what's return values in `PLAN 2`?

Comment: return values are .portrait

Comment: please update the return values in question